# Snakemake: functions as input not working as expected (InputFunctionException with KeyError)

Tags: snakemake

In my case, there is no pattern in the names of input and output files, so I used a dict to map the output to the input file, and then used this dict in the function as input. Please see the codes of Snakemake file below:

```py
in_files = ['in_a', 'in_b']
out_files = ['out_c', 'out_d']

out_to_in_dict = dict()
for in_file, out_file in zip(in_files, out_files):
    out_to_in_dict[out_file] = in_file

rule all:
    input:
        out_files

rule copy_file:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: out_to_in_dict[wildcards.outfile]
    output:
        '{outfile}'
    shell:
        '''
        cp {input} {output}
        '''
```

After executing Snakemake, I got this error:

```
InputFunctionException in line 8 of /home/test.snake:
KeyError: 'in_a'
Wildcards:
outfile=in_a
```

The version of Snakemake I am using is 5.5.3. Could anyone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why but you can fix it by constraining the scope of the wildcards using `wildcard_constraints`:

```
in_files = ['in_a', 'in_b']
out_files = ['out_c', 'out_d']

out_to_in_dict = dict()
for in_file, out_file in zip(in_files, out_files):
    out_to_in_dict[out_file] = in_file

wildcard_constraints:
    outfile= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in out_files]),

rule all:
    input:
        out_files

rule copy_file:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: out_to_in_dict[wildcards.outfile]
    output:
        '{outfile}'
    shell:
        '''
        cp {input} {output}
        '''
```

It's probably related to this   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/snakemake/wVlJW9X-9EU/gSZh4U0_CQAJ but just now I don't see why it applies to your example. Personally, I use `wildcard_constraints` quite liberally as I don't like snakemake's default behaviour of interpreting strings as regexes.

Comment: Thanks! Adding wildcard_constraints worked! Also, I found that the output (or input) can't be exactly equal to the wildcard. Please see the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

I found it worked if I made the output not exactly equal to the wildcard. As shown below, the only change is that the name of final output file was appended with ".txt", and it worked. Not sure if this is a bug of Snakemake?

```py
in_files = ['in_a', 'in_b']
out_files = ['out_c', 'out_d']

out_to_in_dict = dict()
for in_file, out_file in zip(in_files, out_files):
    out_to_in_dict[out_file] = in_file

rule all:
    input:
        [out + '.txt' for out in out_files]

rule copy_file:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: out_to_in_dict[wildcards.outfile]
    output:
        '{outfile}.txt'
    shell:
        '''
        cp {input} {output}
        '''
```